# Using Javascript Hover to replicate Div elsewhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently learning javascript, but I can't seem to work this out myself. I just need a push in the right direction, so I can begin to figure out what I need to start learning. I've found some guidance here, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it my case.

I'm making a periodic table. What I want to happen is, when a user hovers over an element box, a div, that entire div gets replicated at the top of the page, only larger. Here is my website.

www.boulderdan.com

Each element box is enclosed in a div, like the one below, which is getting values via php/mysql. Below is what the html looks like when the page renders.

```
<a href="elementfile.php?action=Oxygen" target="_blank">
<div id="Oxygen" class="element group16 period2">    
<span class="number">8</span><br>    
<span class="symbol">O</span><br>    
<span class="name">Oxygen</span><br>    
<span class="molmass">15.9994</span></div></a>
```

So, when a user hover overs this div, I want all this html to replicated at the top, in a larger box. It's been suggested I use CSS, but I can't figure out how I'd nest the div's properly. I've also looked at jquery, but, again, can't seem to find exactly what I need. Please point me in the right direction! This is a work project, so I must figure this out myself...I just need to know which direction to go in!

Thank you.

Comment: Use `Element.cloneNode(true)` this makes a deep copy of the object. Replace `Element` with a reference to the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var periodicElements = document.querySelectorAll("a");
Array.prototype.map.call(periodicElements, function(element){
  //add two event handlers to all a elements
  //show div
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", showDivAtTop, false);
  //hide div
  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", clearDivAtTop, false);
})

function showDivAtTop(e)
{
  e.stopPropagation();
  var div = e.target.children[0].cloneNode(true) //clone the div.
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.id = "currentElement";
}

function clearDivAtTop(e)
{
  e.stopPropagation();
  //remove the div.
  document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("currentElement"));
}
```

```css
#currentElement{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="elementfile.php?action=Oxygen" target="_blank">
<div id="Oxygen" class="element group16 period2">    
<span class="number">8</span><br>    
<span class="symbol">O</span><br>    
<span class="name">Oxygen</span><br>    
<span class="molmass">15.9994</span></div></a>
```

This does the thing you want.

What is it doing:

1. It selects all `a` elements in the page using `document.querySelectorAll`. This returns a *node list* containing all elements I selected.
2. This node list behaves somewhat like an array, so I can use an array function called map to traverse all the elements. If you want to know how this exactly works read this:  [MDN - Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
3. The I add two event handlers to the `a` element. One fires when the mouse enters the `a` element, the other when it leaves.
4. When you enter the `a` element, we stop all propagation. This means that only the parent fires an event, not the children.
5. We clone the child div and put it on the page.
6. When the mouse leaves the link it removes the cloned div from the page.

On your periodic table you really want to add the event listeners to the table it self and not for 120 elements separately.

Answer (score 0):

use .innerHTML in your parent div where the elements are enclosed.

```
document.getElementById('bigger-div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('original-div').innerHTML;
```

also use % in using width and height sizing in your child elements so the elements inside it will automatically adjust itself to the size of its parent.

```
#bigger-div {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

#inside-bigger-div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery can dramatically reduce the boilerplate code for this task. Let's say that the big element at the top of the document had id "topcontainer":

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseover','.element',function() {
      var content=jQuery(this).html();
        jQuery('#topcontainer').html(content);
});
```

See it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/e9mbryez/

Also, I don't think you want to clear the topcontainer contents on mouseout, for it would lead to a confusing efect when hovering multiple elements in a row.

Comment: But that means adding a lot of extra overhead loading jQuery.

Comment: For this particular task, yes, it might be overkill, but for a project (or website) that involves more DOM manipulation, in the end it's cheaper spending computer power than developer's time.

Comment: I am already using some jquery for creating graphs, so using it here shouldn't be a big deal. This is how easy I thought it would be. Thank you amenadiel and @Mouser for your help. You've saved a wall from a good head bashing and helped me learn, and I very much appreciate it.